# Java Install Fails On Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying installl jave 8 (jre/jdk) in my ubuntu 14.0.4

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

I get below error

```
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-10-17 16:42:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 64.78.224.186, 64.78.224.185
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|64.78.224.186|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-10-17 16:42:10--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.217.152.181, 2600:141b:13:28c::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.217.152.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508276650_49e5615c0aa8584dd72b809fbec787eb [following]
--2017-10-17 16:42:10--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508276650_49e5615c0aa8584dd72b809fbec787eb
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|64.78.224.186|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-17 16:42:11 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
```

looks like it is looking for 8u144 which is not available.

How can i make it look for 8u151?

I did this 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`  -> no luck

Comment: Sorry, I m not sure about, but could you try the following commands in order to try to clear you varcache?
    sudo apt-get autoclean

    sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: the issue has been fixed after a few days

Comment: This issue appears to be happening again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"As a temporary work around":

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u144|JAVA_VERSION=8u152|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="e8a341ce566f32c3d06f6d0f0eeea9a0f434f538d22af949ae58bc86f2eeaae4"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="218b3b340c3f6d05d940b817d0270dfe0cfd657a636bad074dcabe0c111961bf"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_144|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_152|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

And then try installing JAVA again. From this [ubuntuforums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686).

Answer (score 7):

This has been an issue as of today (we hit the webupd8team ppa once a day for `oracle-8-installer`). From past experience it's probably due to the fact that Oracle released their quarterly Java updates overnight ([8u151](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html) and [8u152](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u152-relnotes-3850503.html)), and moved or deleted 8u144. If you dig into the ppa you'll see it only references 8u144.

I'm not that knowledgable on how the webupd8team ppa is managed, but presumably it requires some manual intervention on the maintainer's part to fix the issue.

Comment: I can only assume they are trying to make it hard to automatically upgrade which really puts a kink in anyone trying to maintain a system with a bazillion packages installed.  It will actually discourage people from upgrading to later versions which is what I assume they want to push people to do for security reasons.

Answer (score 6):

I am trying out this solution:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686 -> No luck at the moment

What works for me, I tried manually with this:

1. Create a folder to put JDK

   `mkdir /opt/jdk
    cd /opt`
2. Download the latest JDK:

   `wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz`
3. Extract it

   `tar -zxf jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk`
4. Set it as default

   `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java 100`

   `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/javac 100`

Comment: The answer is right. It provides the only way to face the current issue. Please don't downvote if you don't understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I guess the answer should provide a way to find the current valid link as it appears to by dynamic.  Ie: go to their site look for, find this, clip URL paste in wget command ....  I am stuck now until I figure this out because apparently this problem is not fixed as of 01/16/2018 on either Oracles's part or the package archive maintainers part.

Comment: Apparently one needs an oracle account to access older archived versions.  I logged in with mine and was able to navigate to the appropriate files thought the web interface does not make it easy. I downloaded them.  Also it did not work on Firefox, only on Chrome,

Then after I followed the manual install procedure above for the same version tar.gz the installer was failing to download, copied it to cd /var/cache/oracle-jdk-installers  

Now apt-get upgrade still tries to download the file from the broken link. and fails to upgrade any packages following, leaving broken dependencie

Comment: so after a manual install - is it possible to DISABLE the re-download of the tar.gz file by apt-get so I can complete the upgrade ??

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the Java Oracle tar ball to your home directory, you will need to run the following script to automatically install Java 8.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

JAVA_VER=$(javadd -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/p;')

if [ "${JAVA_VER}" != "18" ]; then
    file_name="jdk-8u172-linux-x64.tar.gz"
    cd ~
    sudo mkdir -p /opt/jdk
    sudo tar -zxf ~/${file_name} -C /opt/jdk

    sudo apt-get remove -y --purge openjdk-\* || true
    cd /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_172/bin

    for j in `ls j*`; do
        sudo update-alternatives --force --install /usr/bin/${j} ${j} /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_172/bin/${j} 100
    done
    sudo update-alternatives --display java
fi
```